# Need a abbreviated State of zipcode 75747 by google map api?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, web

I am using a google map api in order to get the details of a place on behalf of zip code entered by user.

My requirement is if user entered zipcode "75747", then the short name must be returned maximum of two characters as need to pass further in several apis.

Please review the response:- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=75747&sensor=true

Is there any way to get the shortcodes for state of UAE countries or other zipcode?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the response is in json. so you need to `parse` json first and then get the value of the shortcode of the state....

Comment: @prakashtank  i had tried the same but as you can see in response we are not getting any short_name for "Northern Borders Region"

Comment: Please check the link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722911/call-json-element-from-an-api-and-return-result-as-string

Comment: @prakashtank Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me explain by code snippet to get the abbreviated name for "Northern Borders Region" from the json response received from this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=75747&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code here :

```
<html>  
<head></head>
<title>Project 9</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

       var address=encodeURI($('#userInput').val());
       var url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=75747&sensor=true';
       $.getJSON(url, function(data){
          var shortname=data.results[0].address_components[1].short_name;
          alert(shortname);

   });
});
</script>         
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your snippet but if you run the code we get "Northern Borders Region" as a alert but my requirement is **abbreviated form of "Northern Borders Region" (e.g. for Los Angeles, google api gives LA in short_name but for pincode 75747 it's not providing "NBR","NR","NA",etc ) ** anyhow by google api or any other api.